# How to make Linkify link to an SMS client?

Tags: android

Is it possible to `Linkify` a phone number so that clinking the link will offer the option of SMS as well as the various diallers on the device?

Currently when the user clicks the phone number on the screen, they're presented with the following:

[image]

This should also include the phone's messenger. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible if you **customize Linkify** as described in [this Android devloper blog entry](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.at/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html) and use the proper protocol "sms:" like so:

```
sms:<phone_number>[,<phone-number>]*[?body=<message_body>]
```

At least according to [this website](http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2010/01/15/special-links/). I didn't test it myself.

Comment: It doesn't look like it... The first link doesn't mention SMS at all, and the second one appears to be for HTML.

Comment: Even if this works, wouldn't it change all numbers to SMS-only links? I believe the intent is to list both dialers and messaging options in one picker.

Comment: The blog entry describes how to customize linkify. The example regards Wikiwords but if you change the regexp to match phonenumbers and replace "content:" by "sms:" you'd have it. The second one is for HTML as is Linkify which converts your normal text to HTML and applies hyperlinks to URLs, Email-addresses and phone-numbers.

Comment: @Geobits Yes that's true. The normal Linkify adds links with the URI `tel:<phone_number>` to detected phone-numbers and it seems that the SMS-App(s) do not registrate themselves to be able to handle such events, thus they are not listed in the picker.